# Flex 4 Constraint Percentage Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, constraints

I am building a Flex application which uses constraint properties to scale the width of the contents of the application. Here is an example of a `<s:List>` component which uses constraint properties to space it 10% from the left and right:

```
<s:List id="list" left="10%" right="10%" top="10" borderVisible="false"
  contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
  creationComplete="listFetchDataHandler(event)"
  itemRenderer="renderers.FoodMenuRenderer">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllMenuResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
```

Here is a photo of what the above code does vs. what I intended it should do:

[image]

Any ideas on why my code isn't working properly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I believe you can't use percentages in left/right/bottom/top properties it always expects pixel values as a plain number to be specified, I'm not sure why you don't get an error for this scenario though.  It also appears you can possibly make use of constraint columns as described on this page to do percentage based constraints, the other option is to avoid using constraints and rather use a combination of an HGroup 100% with a child Spacer Width 10% A middle container child width 80% and another spacer child with width 10%

Comment: Couldn't fit the link in the previous comment http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7df9.html

Comment: @shaunhusain Thank you for your helpful comment. If you interested, you can see what I pieced together below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know where my confusion came from. I was using `<s:BasicLayout>` which does not have any padding properties. Some how, with that mix up, I was thinking that I could add padding to components using percentages. Only widths can use percentages.

Here is what I used instead to accomplish what I had mentioned above:

```
<s:List id="list" left="{width * 0.1}" width="80%" top="10" borderVisible="false"
  contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
  creationComplete="listFetchDataHandler(event)"
  itemRenderer="renderers.FoodMenuRenderer">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllMenuResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
```

This works as expected.

Comment: Yah I had considered suggesting something like this but I never really like this solution it just doesn't sit right with me, but sometimes you've gotta do what you've gotta do.  Glad you figured out a solution though.